Why does my private GitLab package return "404 Not Found" when trying to install it in a monorepo using pnpm?
I am working on a monorepo project using nx and pnpm. The project contains multiple packages, including @my-org/package1 and @my-org/package2. I have set up a private GitLab package registry to publish and install these packages.
Here’s the workflow:

I published the @my-org/package2 package successfully to the private registry.
Now, I want to use @my-org/package2 as a dependency in the @my-org/package1 package for local development.

However, when I try to install the package in the @my-org/package1 project using pnpm, I get the following error:


404 Not Found: @my-org/package2


Registry Configuration:
I added the following to my .npmrc file:
@my-org:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/packages/npm/:_authToken=<my-token>
always-auth=true


Verified the Package:
I ran pnpm view @my-org/package2, and it shows the package with the correct version in the registry.

Local Linking:
I tried using workspace in pnpm-workspace.yaml:
packages:
  - 'packages/*'

And added this dependency in @my-org/package1’s package.json:
"dependencies": {
  "@my-org/package2": "^0.0.1"
}


Cleared Cache:
I ran pnpm store prune and reinstalled all dependencies.


Environment Details

Package Manager: pnpm
Monorepo Tool: nx
Registry: GitLab Private Package Registry

Questions

Why am I seeing a 404 error for the package, even though it is published and visible in the registry?

How can I set up my monorepo to use the @my-org/package2 package in @my-org/package1 for local development without this issue?



Does it has the permission to download @my-org/package2?
